# Get Values from Datagridview related to to certain values in another column c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

So here is my problem. I have not been coding very long and i have been pulling my hair out on this issue for 2 days now and cant get an answer that works...

Form1 has a datagridview with 3 columns and multiple rows of data.
If i press a button on Form1 i need it to populate all the values in column[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsBej.png) that has a certain value in column[2] and then display it in a textbox on Form2.

Example:

[Datagrid example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsBej.png)

So if I click a button i want to pull all the amounts for car1 and display the total in a textbox on form2.

```
Form2 obj = new Form2();
public void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
String searchValue = "Car1";
        int rowIndex = 1;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
            {
                rowIndex = row.Index;
                obj.Controls["TextBox1"].Text = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Selected.ToString();
                obj.Show();

            }
            else
            {
               break;
            }


        }
    }
```

I just get the answer "true" in my textbox

I hope this makes sense

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to show what you've tried so far and what exactly it is you're having issues with. So far your question comes across as "please write all the code for me" which will get closed. If you can do that you're more likely to get some answers that help you.

Comment: I can help but dont know what is certain value ? so if column[1] has rows that greater than column[2] rows? something like that?

Comment: Ahh ok. I will add the code that i used last that got me the closest to where i wanted to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you break `foreach` loop. As i understand, you want all other amounts of Car1. Right? Check this out:

```
    Form2 obj = new Form2();
    public void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String searchValue = "Car1";
            int amount = 0;
             foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
           {
                 if(row.Cells["Type"].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue)
                 {
                     amount+ = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Amount"].Value.ToString())
                 }
           }   

            if(amount > 0 )
           {
              obj.Controls["TextBox1"].Text = amount.ToString();
           }
           else
           {
             obj.Controls["TextBox1"].Text = "No car found!";  
           }

           obj.Show();
        }
```

Also you need to control if Amount is a number or not.

Comment: Thank You. That helped a lot. I see now where i made the mistake also

Comment: @Chris glad to help